# How to open a new file to write in perl with sudo permission

Tags: perl, file-io, sudo

I'm trying to open a new file and write something to it in a linux environment. In general the operating directory needs sudo privileges to create/write to a new file. In perl how can I programmatically achieve this? I want the file handle to open with sudo in order to avoid permission denied error.

I saw few of the old posts on this but none of the solution worked for me. I know one solution is to run the perl script with sudo privileges but I want to perform the operation of writing inside the script, please suggest

My code is something like this -

```
open(my $fh, ">", $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!"; # Dies with the error
```

I also tried

```
open(my $fh, '-|', 'sudo', '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!"; # Asking for password
```

Answer (score 6):

Your attempt tells `sudo` to execute a program named `>`.

You need a program that will create the file, read from its stdin, and print out what it read to the file.

After making sure the file name is safe, you can use the following:

```perl
my $qfn = ...;   # The validated path.

open( my $pipe, "|-",
   "sudo",
      "/usr/bin/sh",
         "-c",
         'exec /usr/bin/cat >"$1"',
         "dummy",
         $qfn
)
   or die( "Can't execute sudo: $!\n" );

...

close( $pipe );
die( "Error cleaning up child: $!\n"              ) if $? == -1;
die( "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"  ) if $? >> 8;
```